# typescript method override does not work

Tags: javascript, class, typescript, overriding

I have a baseclass A and an extended class B that overrides A's fetch method.
However when I call B.fetch() it logs 'baseclass'. Why doesn't it call the method definition defined in B?

```
     class A {
        protected apiPath: string = ''
        static async fetch (id = null, Model = this, apiPath = this.apiPath): Promise<any> {
            console.log('basefetch')
            let url = apiPath
            if(id) url += '/' + id
            let { data } = await axios.get(url)
            let item: any = new Model(data)
            return item
        }
    }

    class B extends A {
        static async fetch(id = null, Model = this, apiPath = this.apiPath): Promise<Data> {
            console.log('childfetch')
            let {data} = await axios.get(apiPath)
            if (typeof data.challenge.participating == 'undefined') {
                data.challenge.participating = null
            }
            if (typeof data.challenge.progress == 'undefined') {
                data.challenge.progress = null
            }
            return new Model(data)
        }

class SomeOtherModule {
    async doSomething() {
        let b: B = await B.fetch()
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the `fetch` method from class B? can you post that part?

Comment: @Niladri I have added it

Comment: @Chris `B.fetch()` returns a `Promise<Data>` and can not be assigned to `b` of type `B`. I assume this is all pseudo code, because `apiPath = this.apiPath` in your method signature will also not compile because `apiPath` isn't static. Can you provide plunkr that show's your behavior.

Comment: I just updated the question with how it is actually called

Answer (score 1):

Well the method signatures are different. In A you are returning `Promise<any>` but in B you are returning `Promise<Data>`.

You can see in [this snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20fetch%20()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20'basefetch'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20fetch()%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20'childfetch'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20aVal%3A%20string%20%3D%20A.fetch()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(%60aVal%3A%20%24%7BaVal%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20bVal%3A%20string%20%3D%20B.fetch()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(%60bVal%3A%20%24%7BbVal%7D%60)%3B) that what you are trying to do certainly can work:

```
class A {
  static fetch (): string {
    return 'basefetch';
  }
}

class B extends A {
  static fetch(): any {
    return 'childfetch';
  }
}

let aVal: string = A.fetch();
console.log(`aVal: ${aVal}`);

let bVal: string = B.fetch();
console.log(`bVal: ${bVal}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Static members are assigned to the constructor function. You have to call it like `B.fetch(...)`.

Resulting js code for your example classes:

```
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
    }
    A.fetch = function () {
        console.log("A fetch");
    };
    return A;
}());
var B = (function (_super) {
    tslib_1.__extends(B, _super);
    function B() {
        return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
    }
    B.fetch = function () {
        console.log("B fetch");
    };
    return B;
}(A));
```

This means you called `A.fetch(...)`.